# How to rewrite a cucumber scenario in a simple way?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-java

I wanted to rewrite a scenario (refactor) the same way I do in methods or variables

Already tried "refactor" function of Intellij

```
Scenario: verify input login
   Given I insert some text
   Then The input is filled
```

So, let's try to change the given phrase to:

```
 Given I insert any text
```

How to do that with single steps, instead of changing every phrase along others features?

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring cucumber is only straightforward if you keep your steps very simple. As soon as you add parameters things become alot more complex, as different statements may match the same step definition.

What I do is

- a global search for the phrase in question
- a look at the step definition dealing implementing the step
- make a decision based on the above as to what sort of refactor I need

Some of the refactors I might need are

- extract a helper method from the step definition
- create a similar step e.g. I might have several steps that do the same thing. This isn't a problem so long as each step definition calls the same helper method
- create a different step, because I've discovered two different things e.g. valid text and invalid text

...

Personally I don't think a refactoring tool is a good fit for cucumber because cucumber features are not code. Anything that changes a step without you first reading that step in all its contexts is likely to make your cukes worse.